# How do I add a second hyperlink to an anchor that is already occupied by JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, anchor

Here is my reference page:  http://ca.pockethm.com/setupaccount/feature-videos_library.php

I am using Dynamic Drive's "[Dynamic Ajax](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)" script to change the content in a 'containerarea' div. Here is a sample of my actual anchor code:

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('videos-maintenance/appliances-repair_fridge_gasket.php', 'contentarea');">
<img src="http://aaaa.pockethm.com/images/icon-youtubeTV.png" alt="Repair a Refrigerator Door Gasket" class="icon-image" border="0" />
<div class="icon-text">Repair a Refrigerator Door Gasket</div>
</a>
```

What I need is to have the page jump to an `<a name="videoTop">` anchor positioned above the video window upon clicking the YouTube icon to watch a particular video in preparation for when I add a lot more videos.  I've tried onclick, onfocus, onmouseover, and a variety of other code mashes....to no avail.  There's a strong possibility I'm doing it wrong, though.

Thanks in advance for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stack it in the inline code:

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.hash='#videoTop';ajaxpage('videos-maintenance/appliances-repair_fridge_gasket.php', 'contentarea');">
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @Diodeus.  That only partially works, though.  If I scroll back down to the video links and select a second video, then the script fails to work a second time because of document.location.hash='#videoTop'.  The #videoTop is already embedded in the URL. Any way to remedy this so that every click on any video link always works during the same session?

Comment: Nevermind.  The fix was easy.  Instead of 'location.hash', use 'location.href'.  No-brainer.  Thank again @Diodeus.